# Unable to parse YAML in config.yml file when I deployed to circle-ci

Tags: yaml, config, circleci, lint

**situation**

- I'm issuing with a config processing error in my personal project

**success**

- I added AWS s3 and CloudFront  and deploy was a success on circle-ci

**fail**

- I added linting that's causing the error  but I'm not using tab t for
  indentation

this is my [repo](https://github.com/taiga-programming/cinema-app/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml)

**error**

```
!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
 Unable to parse YAML
 while scanning for the next token
 found character '\\t(TAB)' that cannot start any token. (Do not use \\t(TAB) for indentation)
  in 'string', line 57, column 34:
           - *show-current-branch-name\t
                                      ^
 
 -------
 Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
 Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a TAB char at the end of line 57. remove it and it should pass.